# Replace duplicate elements in a numpy array based on a range

Tags: python, numpy, random, duplicates, numpy-ndarray

I have an 1d numpy array `arr` as below:

```
arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
```

For the duplicate elements, I wish to randomly select any one of the indices containing the same element and replace it with a value missing in between `0` and `arr.shape[0]`.

e.g. In the given array, 7 is present in indices 1, 4 and 9. Hence, I wish to randomly select an index between 1, 4 and 9 and set its value by randomly selecting some element like 8, which is absent in the array. In the end, `arr` should contain `arr.shape[0]` unique elements lying between 0 and `arr.shape[0] - 1` (both inclusive)

How can I do this efficiently using Numpy (possibly without needing to use any explicit loop)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one based on `np.isin` -

```
def create_uniques(arr):
    # Get unique ones and the respective counts
    unq,c = np.unique(arr,return_counts=1)

    # Get mask of matches from the arr against the ones that have 
    # respective counts > 1, i.e. the ones with duplicates
    m = np.isin(arr,unq[c>1])

    # Get the ones that are absent in original array and shuffle it
    newvals = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(arr)),arr[~m])
    np.random.shuffle(newvals)

    # Assign the shuffled values into the duplicate places to get final o/p
    arr[m] = newvals
    return ar
```

Sample runs -

```
In [53]: arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])

In [54]: create_uniques(arr)
Out[54]: array([9, 7, 0, 1, 6, 4, 8, 2, 3, 5])

In [55]: arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])

In [56]: create_uniques(arr)
Out[56]: array([9, 4, 0, 5, 6, 2, 7, 1, 3, 8])

In [57]: arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])

In [58]: create_uniques(arr)
Out[58]: array([9, 4, 0, 1, 7, 2, 6, 8, 3, 5])
```

Comment: This replaces the next occurrence of a value with a non-present value as opposed to a random index of a value.

Comment: arr = np.array([3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 8]) causes an error saying ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,)

Comment: new_vals = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(arr.max()),arr)
In this line, instead of arr.max(), arr.shape[0] does the job correctly.

Comment: @ThomasHaz OP wants the former - non-present value in the range - 0 to arr.shape[0].

Comment: @ThomasHaz is actually correct. Any way to make this random?

Comment: @SomnathRakshit Not sure If I follow you. Are you looking to assign those new values in random order? Could you clarify on your expected randomness?

Comment: I wish to randomly select one of the duplicate elements. For e.g., I wish to randomly select 1, 4 and 9 and then replace the element present in that index.

Comment: @SomnathRakshit Are you saying you want to replace only one of the duplicate elements? For e.g.,for the indices - 1,4,9, select one of them and replace it and no change for the other two elements?

Comment: @Divakar `[9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7]` could become `[9, 6, 0, 4, 8, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7]`, where the resulting array has no duplicates, but the selected duplicate to change is chosen at random.

Comment: @Divakar: ThomasHaz is correct. That is my intention.

Comment: @ThomasHaz Thanks for the explanation. Hopefully this time it works out with OP.

Comment: Some explanation would be a valuable help for posterity!

Comment: @kmario23 Added.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Divakar's answer (and I have basically no experience in python so this is likely a very roundabout and unpython way of doing it but):

```
import numpy as np
def create_uniques(arr):
    np.random.seed()
    indices = []
    for i, x in enumerate(arr):
        indices.append([arr[i], [j for j, y in enumerate(arr) if y == arr[i]]])
        indices[i].append(np.random.choice(indices[i][1]))
        indices[i][1].remove(indices[i][2])
    sidx = arr.argsort()
    b = arr[sidx]
    new_vals = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(len(arr)),arr)
    arr[sidx[1:][b[:-1] == b[1:]]] = new_vals
    for i,x in enumerate(arr):
        if x == indices[i][0] and i != indices[i][2]:
            arr[i] = arr[indices[i][2]]
            arr[indices[i][2]] = x
    return arr
```

Sample:

```
arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
print(arr)
print(create_uniques(arr))
arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
print(create_uniques(arr))
arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
print(create_uniques(arr))
arr = np.array([9, 7, 0, 4, 7, 4, 2, 2, 3, 7])
print(create_uniques(arr))
```

Outputs:

```
[9 7 0 4 7 4 2 2 3 7]
[9 7 0 4 6 5 2 1 3 8]
[9 8 0 4 6 5 1 2 3 7]
[9 8 0 4 6 5 2 1 3 7]
[9 7 0 5 6 4 2 1 3 8]
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. However, @Dibakar's current code is cleaner as well as faster. Hence, I have marked his answer as the accepted one.